# CSS class for rendering divs dynamically on half of page

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck in rendering div via ng-repeat. I want to render the coming divs in ng-repeat one by one covering half the page.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-repeat="field in selectedfields" ng-if="!selectedfields[$index].allowedValues || selectedfields[$index].allowedValues.length === 0 ">
          <label class="control-label" for="domain">{{field.name}} </label>
          <input placeholder="{{field.name}}" class="form-control"  type="text" id="domain">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-repeat="field in selectedfields" ng-if="selectedfields[$index].allowedValues.length >= 1">
           <label class="control-label" for="{{field.name}}">{{field.name}} </label>
          <select class="form-control">
               <option value="{{allowedValue.name}}" ng-repeat="allowedValue in field.allowedValues" ng-model="field.allowedValues">{{allowedValue.name}}</option>
            </select>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

The divs(textboxes/dropdown) under the parent div should appear one by one covering half the page, but they are coming on full page. Each div is rendering on next line. Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong in giving the css class?

Comment: What do you mean by "half the page, but they are coming on full page?"

Comment: What i meant is, they are coming on next line, instead of coming side-byside

Comment: try `col-xs-6` instead of col-md-6

Comment: I mentioned the solution to my question, in the comments section of the given answer

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final layout should be

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="row">
  <!-- ng-repeat stuff goes here !-->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: i don't think so .. we need also to have `row` class. And for full page it's `container-fluid`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Indeed they need a `row` class too.. well pointed out !

Comment: I did the same
<div class = "col-md-12">
<div class = "row">
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

Comment: instead of container in parent div, please change it to col-md-12, then I can mark it as correct

Comment: I don't think your proposed solution makes any sense. Does that mean you have other parent divs with container/container-fluid classes?

Comment: yes, I have a parent div which contains class as row, and the proposed solution comes under that div